# Modify the knockout script on the checkout onepage

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I want to like the items that are in the customers cart when he tries to checkout.

Right now, it looks like this:

[image: Current state]

And code looks like this:

[image: a gets no href]

The questions is, how can I get the `<a data-bind="href: $parent.url">` element to actually hold the products URL? How can take a look at `$parent` anyhow? We are using Magento 2.0.6.